# Can't use context, make luatex format, bad directory

Tags: luatex, context

I've installed context in standalone few day ago but I can't make it work. I'm using W10 Pro x64.
When I run `context.exe <path/to/my/file.tex>`, it show many lines but it always end up by `return value: error` Later it says `error, no format found with name: cont-en, aborting`. But I dont think this the real problem.

Few lines upper, it says `executing runner 'make luatex format': "C:/Program Files/Context/tex/texmf-win64/bin"/luatex --ini  --lua="C:/Program Files/Context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkiv/luat-cod.lua" "C:/Program Files/Context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkiv/cont-en.mkiv" '"C:/Program Files/Context/tex/texmf-win64/bin"' Is not an internal command.`
It try to run C:/Program Files/Context/tex/texmf-win64/***bin"/luatex*** So for sure, I get an error.

If i run `"C:/Program Files/Context/tex/texmf-win64/bin/luatex" --ini  --lua="C:/Program Files/Context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkiv/luat-cod.lua" "C:/Program Files/Context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkiv/cont-en.mkiv"` It doesn"t end it up with a file but it doesnt give me an error I think it's because this command is just a part of the process.

I've tried to check my path, it looks ok and as much config file as I found.

My only supposition is that, it is impossible to run context from a directory with blank space. But I haven't tried it yet.

Does someone get this error before or know ho to solve ? I've tried to check some lua files but I don't get anything in.

My complete log: https://hastebin.com/niweluxocu.sql

EDIT: I remember I haven't installed ruby but it doesn't seems to be the problem

Comment: I'd suggest you to download/reinstall your distribution from here: http://www.pragma-ade.nl/install.htm, execute setpath.bat and then try using `context.exe <filename>.tex` again.

Comment: I'll try. I stay you tuned up.

Comment: Just en it up with the same error.
When I run install.bat, I got `running: C:/Program Files/Context/tex/texmf-win64/bin/mtxrun.exe --generate
'C:/Program' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.
mtx-install     | running: C:/Program Files/Context/tex/texmf-win64/bin/context.exe --make en
'C:/Program' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.`

Comment: So I tried to run it mylself with "". No prbelm for the first but the second end up with `executing runner 'make luametatex format': "C:/Program Files/Context/tex/texmf-win64/bin"/luametatex --ini  --lua="C:/Program Files/Context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkxl/luat-cod.lmt" "C:/Program Files/Context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkxl/cont-en.mkxl"`

And same error when I try to precess a file

Comment: I'm going to test it (I'm on Linux right now). Just curious, do you have administrator privileges wrt the folder where ConTeXt is installed?

Comment: So, yes I need to be administrator to download files. I've installed it in a directory without blank space and seems to work, the other difference is I have installed it with powershell, not cmd. I'll now try to install in in my directory with space with powershell

Comment: Breaking news, I've installed it in my directory with space without admin rights. It was the oter script that need admin rights. The other difference it that, I have used Powershell instead of cmd

Comment: The problem is definitely cmd, the last install works well with powershell but with cmd no way, cmd as User and cmd as Admin.

Comment: Oh, I see. ConTeXt seems to be confused when the path includes spaces. I remember this issue discussed in the mail list, but I don't remember when. As a workaround you can move your folder to a location without spaces in its name, just in case (I put it in `C`) : `C:/Context/tex/texmf-win64/bin/context.exe <filename>.tex` does its job in Windows 7 (x64).

Comment: Looks likes is that. Thanks for your help !